# AttributeError: module 'exoplanet.distributions' has no attribute 'Angle'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

```py
    import exoplanet as xo
    import pymc3 as pm
    import theano.tensor as tt
    
    def build_model(mask=None, start=None):
        if mask is None:
            mask = np.ones(len(x), dtype=bool)
        with pm.Model() as model:
    
            # Parameters for the stellar properties
            mean = pm.Normal("mean", mu=0.0, sd=10.0)
            u_star = xo.distributions.QuadLimbDark("u_star")
    
            # Stellar parameters from Huang et al (2018)
            M_star_huang = 1.094, 0.039
            R_star_huang = 1.10, 0.023
            m_star = pm.Normal("m_star", mu=M_star_huang[0], sd=M_star_huang[1])
            r_star = pm.Normal("r_star", mu=R_star_huang[0], sd=R_star_huang[1])
    
            # Prior to require physical parameters
            pm.Potential("m_star_prior", tt.switch(m_star > 0, 0, -np.inf))
            pm.Potential("r_star_prior", tt.switch(r_star > 0, 0, -np.inf))
    
            # Orbital parameters for the planets
            logP = pm.Normal("logP", mu=np.log(bls_period), sd=1)
            t0 = pm.Normal("t0", mu=bls_t0, sd=1)
            b = pm.Uniform("b", lower=0, upper=1, testval=0.5)
            logr = pm.Normal("logr", sd=1.0,
                             mu=0.5*np.log(1e-3*np.array(bls_depth))+np.log(R_star_huang[0]))
            r_pl = pm.Deterministic("r_pl", tt.exp(logr))
            ror = pm.Deterministic("ror", r_pl / r_star)
    
            # This is the eccentricity prior from Kipping (2013):
            # https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4982
            ecc = pm.Beta("ecc", alpha=0.867, beta=3.03, testval=0.1)
            omega = xo.distributions.Angle("omega",shape=2, testval=np.zeros(2))
    
            # Transit jitter & GP parameters
            logs2 = pm.Normal("logs2", mu=np.log(np.var(y[mask])), sd=10)
            logw0_guess = np.log(2*np.pi/10)
            logw0 = pm.Normal("logw0", mu=logw0_guess, sd=10)
    
            # We'll parameterize using the maximum power (S_0 * w_0^4) instead of
            # S_0 directly because this removes some of the degeneracies between
            # S_0 and omega_0
            logpower = pm.Normal("logpower",
                                 mu=np.log(np.var(y[mask]))+4*logw0_guess,
                                 sd=10)
            logS0 = pm.Deterministic("logS0", logpower - 4 * logw0)
    
            # Tracking planet parameters
            period = pm.Deterministic("period", tt.exp(logP))
    
            # Orbit model
            orbit = xo.orbits.KeplerianOrbit(
                r_star=r_star, m_star=m_star,
                period=period, t0=t0, b=b,
                ecc=ecc, omega=omega)
    
            # Compute the model light curve using starry
            light_curves = xo.StarryLightCurve(u_star).get_light_curve(
                orbit=orbit, r=r_pl, t=x[mask], texp=texp)*1e3
            light_curve = pm.math.sum(light_curves, axis=-1) + mean
            pm.Deterministic("light_curves", light_curves)
    
            # GP model for the light curve
            kernel = xo.gp.terms.SHOTerm(log_S0=logS0, log_w0=logw0, Q=1/np.sqrt(2))
            gp = xo.gp.GP(kernel, x[mask], tt.exp(logs2) + tt.zeros(mask.sum()), J=2)
            pm.Potential("transit_obs", gp.log_likelihood(y[mask] - light_curve))
            pm.Deterministic("gp_pred", gp.predict())
    
            # Fit for the maximum a posteriori parameters, I've found that I can get
            # a better solution by trying different combinations of parameters in turn
            if start is None:
                start = model.test_point
            map_soln = xo.optimize(start=start, vars=[logs2, logpower, logw0])
            map_soln = xo.optimize(start=map_soln, vars=[logr])
            map_soln = xo.optimize(start=map_soln, vars=[b])
            map_soln = xo.optimize(start=map_soln, vars=[logP, t0])
            map_soln = xo.optimize(start=map_soln, vars=[u_star])
            map_soln = xo.optimize(start=map_soln, vars=[logr])
            map_soln = xo.optimize(start=map_soln, vars=[b])
            map_soln = xo.optimize(start=map_soln, vars=[ecc, omega])
            map_soln = xo.optimize(start=map_soln, vars=[mean])
            map_soln = xo.optimize(start=map_soln, vars=[logs2, logpower, logw0])
            map_soln = xo.optimize(start=map_soln)
        return model, map_soln 
    model0, map_soln0 = build_model()
```

1. This is a code about the exoplanets and took from https://docs.exoplanet.codes/en/v0.1.5/tutorials/tess/ this URL. I have tried to execute and once I did generated an error **AttributeError: module 'exoplanet.distributions' has no attribute 'Angle'**
2. Please note that already install the exoplanet, pymc3, and theano.tensor.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Documentation https://docs.exoplanet.codes/en/latest/user/api/ doesn't mention `Angle` under `exoplanet.distributions` nor anywhere else in the API.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo yes, but here https://docs.exoplanet.codes/en/v0.1.5/tutorials/tess/ it's included. I got the code from here.

Comment: And there https://docs.exoplanet.codes/en/v0.4.4/user/api/ mentioned it as well. But my problem is when running the code, the above atributeerror generated.

Comment: According to the change log https://docs.exoplanet.codes/en/latest/changes/ `Angle` was removed in version 0.5.0.